# Gaussian beam hitting lens at an angle

Tags: optics, lenses

I'm designing an optical system for an experiment I'm running. In the situation I'm dealing with, I need to be able to understand the behavior of a gaussian beam passing through a lens. All the stuff I've found online have taught me a lot about Gaussian beams and how they behave when they hit a lens with a given focal length. However, at the end of my setup, I have a situation in which a Gaussian beam will be hitting a converging lens at an angle such that it is not hitting the lens straight on. If I ignore aberrations and assume a thin lens, how does the angle of incidence affect the outgoing beam?